CORS Error while connecting my angular application to gateway spring boot
When I am hitting my signup url directly to the service controller its running fine and saving user and giving 200 response, but when same thing I am hitting through gateway, My user is getting saved but taking a lot of time + showing this error + my response is coming 200 :
Error:
signup:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/auth/register' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:4200, *', but only one is allowed. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Request URL:
http://localhost:8080/auth/register
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
200 OK
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
My backend code of gateway is:
yml file:
cloud:
  discovery:
    enabled: true
  gateway:
    globalcors:
      corsConfigurations:
        '[/**]':
          allowedOrigins: "http://localhost:4200"       # Allows requests from any origin
          allowedMethods: "GET,POST"       # Allows all HTTP methods (GET, POST, etc.)
          allowedHeaders: "*"       # Allows all headers

   @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Object config) {
        return ((exchange, chain) -> {
        if(validator.isSecured.test(exchange.getRequest()))
        {

            if(!exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().containsKey(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)){
                throw new TokenMissingException("Token is not present");
            }
            String authHeader= exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION).get(0);
            if(authHeader!=null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                authHeader=authHeader.substring(7);
            }
            try {
                    jwtValidation.validateToken(authHeader);
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                    throw new TokenMissingException("Not authorized to access the request");
            }
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
        });
    }
}

My frontend code is:
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit{

  user : User = new User();

  constructor(private signupService: SignupService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  
  registerUser(){
    console.log('User to register:', this.user);

    this.signupService.registerUser(this.user).subscribe(
      data =>  {  console.log("User  registered Successfully",data);
        alert("User is registered")
      },
      error => {
        console.error('Error registering user:', error);
        alert("User not registered")
      }
    )
  }

const BASE_URL="http://localhost:8080/auth";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SignupService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  registerUser(user: User): Observable<Object>{
      return this.http.post(BASE_URL+"/register",user);
  }

}


Add the following to your application.yml in Spring Gateway
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Origin, RETAIN_UNIQUE

This removes the duplicate headers causing the issue
